# Python script returning youtube livechat messages with youtube API returns weird KeyError and NoneType errors after some time

Tags: python, json, python-requests, youtube-api, keyerror

I am trying to make a python script that displays a live stream chat through the command line. I found a comment by user:10914284 in the question [Can't get live chat from stream I do not own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57263074/cant-get-live-chat-from-stream-i-do-not-own) and I modified his answer a little bit. This program works for a little bit, but then it raises two types of errors after a while. It can display the livestream chat for a little while then it raises a KeyError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_chat.py", line 58, in <module>
    print_message()
  File "get_chat.py", line 54, in print_message
    for i in range(len(messages['items'])):
KeyError: 'items'
```

Strangely, if I try to run the program multiple times it raises a TypeError, even though a couple of minutes ago the script ran just fine.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_chat.py", line 22, in <module>
    vID = r.get('items')[0]['id']['videoId']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

The code:

```
import requests
import json

API_KEY = 'YOUTUBE_API_KEY_HERE'
channelID = 'UC9pYOJPB5UYlMlGKKZWo-Bw' # Random youtube channel that is currently broadcasting a youtube livestream

params = {
        'part': 'id',
        'key': API_KEY,
        'channelId': channelID,
        'eventType': 'live',
        'type': 'video',
        'order': 'viewCount',
        'fields': 'items(id(videoId))'
        }

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search'
r = requests.get(url, headers=None, params=params).json()

vID = r.get('items')[0].get('id').get('videoId')
#vID = r.get('items')[0]['id']['videoId'] returns same KeyError

params = {
        'part': 'liveStreamingDetails,statistics,snippet',
        'key': API_KEY,
        'id': vID,
        'fields': 'items(id,liveStreamingDetails(activeLiveChatId,concurrentViewers,actualStartTime),' + \
                  'snippet(channelId,channelTitle,description,liveBroadcastContent,publishedAt,thumbnails,title),statistics)'
        }

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos'
r = requests.get(url, headers=None, params=params).json()

streamData = dict(r.get('items')[0])

chatID = streamData['liveStreamingDetails']['activeLiveChatId']

params = {
        'part': 'snippet',
        'key': API_KEY,
        'liveChatId': chatID,
        #'profileImageSize': 720,
        'maxResults': 200
        }

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveChat/messages'

def print_message():
        while True:
                messages = requests.get(url, headers=None, params=params).json()
                for i in range(len(messages['items'])):
                        print(messages['items'][i]['snippet']['displayMessage'])


print_message()
```

I have some hypotheses for why these might be happening. For the KeyError, maybe when there are more than 200 messages (`'maxResults': 200`) it raises the error. I tried changing the `''maxResults'` value to something like 2000 but the error still appears.
The TypeError only appears if you try to run the script multiple times, and after some time, it raises this error. I think this might be happening because I am requesting and the messages overlap? And somehow it is out of range? The other possibility is that I have used all my google quotas for the day and the API wont return me anything.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, I do check the key first

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    response = get_liveChatId()
    items = response["items"]
    for item in items:
        if "liveChatId" in item['snippet']:
            print(item['snippet']['liveChatId']) #Get the liveChatId
        else:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have spent all your daily quota.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).