# Python won't read Live Chat messages through YouTube Live Chat API because of one problematic line of code

Tags: python, api, youtube-api

I am currently working on YouTube Chat Reader script on Python and there is this one line that doesnt work ever.

It's `vID = r.get['items']('id(videoId)')[0]`

I have tried 14 different codes on that one line and none of them worked.

Original code is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59761511/python-script-returning-youtube-livechat-messages-with-youtube-api-returns-weird) with little customizations so it can copy actual messages.

```
params = {
        'part': 'id',
        'key': API_KEY,
        'channelId': channelID,
        'eventType': 'live',
        'type': 'video',
        'order': 'viewCount',
        'fields': 'items(id(videoId))'
        }

print("JS Loaded")

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search'
r = requests.get(url, headers=None, params=params).json()

print("API Loaded")

vID = r.get['items']('id(videoId)')[0]
```

Here's a little piece of the code that is problematic. Especially the `vID = r.get['items']('id(videoId)')[0]` part.

```
Try 1: vID = r.get('items')[0]['id']['videoId'] Result: IndexError: list index out of range

Try 2: vID = r.get['items'][0]['id']['videoId'] Result: TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Try 3: vID = r.get['items']['id']['videoId'][0] Result: TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable 

Try 4: vID = r.get('items')['id']['videoId'][0] Result: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Try 5: vID = r.get('items')('id')('videoId')[0] Result: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Try 6: vID = r.get('items')[0]('id')('videoId') Result: IndexError: list index out of range

Try 7: vID = r.get['items(id(videoId)'][0] Result: TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable  

Try 8: vID = r.get('items(id(videoId)')[0] Result: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Try 9: vID = r.get('items')('id(videoId)')[0] Result: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Try 10: vID = r.get('items')[0]('id(videoId)') Result: IndexError: list index out of range

Try 11: vID = r.get['items'][0]('id(videoId)') Result: TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable 

Try 12: vID = r.get['items'][0]['id(videoId)'] Result: TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable 

Try 13: vID = r.get['items']['id(videoId)'][0] Result: TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable       

Try 14: vID = r.get['items']('id(videoId)')[0] Result: TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

Here's every attempt to fix the code and none of them works. There's also error message that it gave me.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, var `r` represents a response from the `requests` library. The `.json()` ensures that the body content of var `r` (the response of your request) is transformed from JSON to a python object (dictionary).

Knowing this, it doesn't make sense to do `r.get['items']` as the correct syntax is `r.get('whatever_key_here')`.

Now, you will need to know what the format is of the returned object if you want to go further. `r.get('items')` returns the value of key 'items' in the object. If that value is a list, then `r.get('items')[0]` will return the first value of that list. If that value is an dictionary itself and you want the value of key 'id', then `r.get('items')[0].get('id')` will return that value.

As I do not know the format of the response you are getting with `r`, I can't go into the specifics. Maybe if you do `print(r)` after the creation of `r` you can share the actual object that is created for you and then we can point out what syntax you are looking for :)

Comment: I'll do what you requested soon. I'm not mean but could you give me a little TL;DR version of it and make it clear what kind of changes i gotta do so it can work.

Comment: I don't know how to shorten this any further to be honest, this is all very basic dictionary and list stuff. If the above was to complicated, I would recommend to do a few tutorials on Python Dictionaries and Python Lists.

Comment: `print(r)` gave `{'items': [{'id': {'videoId': 'beh51ctWMVs'}}]}`

Comment: Of you want the videoId value, then `r.get("items")[0].get("id").get("videoId")` will return `beh51ctWMVs`