# Getting live chat of a broadcast not hosted by my account

Tags: node.js, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am struggling with YouTube Data API v3. I want to track live chat on broadcasts kept by ID on my server and not necessarily hosted by my account. How to do that?

The endpoint `liveStreams/list` seems to work only with my broadcasts so it does not seem possible to use it for other streams.

I have found [Can't get live chat from stream I do not own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57263074/cant-get-live-chat-from-stream-i-do-not-own) , but it does not seem like a correct solution too. I have obtained `/videos/list` with the ID of a broadcast, and it did not give me `liveChatID` or anything similar.

Is there another way to do that?

Comment: Please post the culprit video ID such that to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Tested with these two: jJ9OhaGeJGM (not mine), mGdJKbjbNTQ (mine)

Comment: The video `jJ9OhaGeJGM` has this `activeLiveChatId`: `Cg0KC2pKOU9oYUdlSkdNKicKGFVDcjd2UWV5dC1KcEFrVWkxQk9EdEhDZxILako5T2hhR2VKR00`. The video `mGdJKbjbNTQ` is private, thus cannot get its  `activeLiveChatId` even if it has one.

Comment: How did you get it? Could you post a request, please. My request does not get `activeLiveChatId` as a response.

Comment: The URL `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=jJ9OhaGeJGM&part=id,liveStreamingDetails&fields=items(id,liveStreamingDetails(activeLiveChatId))&maxResults=1&key=...` produces the following JSON response: `{"items":[{"id":"jJ9OhaGeJGM","liveStreamingDetails":{"activeLiveChatId":"Cg0KC2pKOU9oYUdlSkdNKicKGFVDcjd2UWV5dC1KcEFrVWkxQk9EdEhDZxILako5T2hhR2VKR00"}}]}`.

Comment: thanks, I will try it

Comment: Most likely you forgot to add `liveStreamingDetails` to the `part` request parameter. The `fields` parameter is not required; I used it above only to have a shorter JSON response from the API, since was interested to see `activeLiveChatId` only.